# Help with calculating Lagrangian with scalar potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

I was reading Schwartz's QFT, I came across a lagrangian density,

$$ \mathcal{L} = -\frac12 h \Box h + \frac13 \lambda h^3 + Jh ,\tag{3.69} $$

Calculating the Euler-Lagrange equation,
$$ \partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}h)} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial h} = 0 \tag{1}, $$

the equation of motion is given as
$$ \Box h -\lambda h^2 - J = 0. \tag{3.70} $$

I tried calculation. After I integrated by parts, I got

$$ \mathcal L'=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu h\partial^\mu h+\frac{1}{3}\lambda h^3+Jh $$

Now I have a problem to calculate
$$ \frac 12 \partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial (\partial_{\nu}h\partial^{\nu}h)}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}h)}, $$
which seems to be
$$\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} h  $$

Why
$$ \frac 12 \partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial (\partial_{\nu}h\partial^{\nu}h)}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}h)}  = 0 $$
for $\mu \neq \nu$ ?

Related post: [Help with taking derivative of Lagrangian scalar model of graviton](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/339784/help-with-taking-derivative-of-lagrangian-scalar-model-of-graviton)